# hyperbolic n-gon with geodesic edges and area 7

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I got stuck solving this following problem:

For which $n\geq 3$ exists a hyperbolic n-gon with geodesic edges and surface area 7?

I know the following things:

the sum of the outer angles of a n-gon is equal to 2$\pi$. 
And the sum of the inner angle of a n-gon is equal to: $(n-2)\pi$

I also know the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get further.

Comment: Isn’t your statement about outer and inner angles true only in the Euclidean case?